# Какой формат изображений можно использовать в андроид приложениях?

Tags: android, android-studio

Всем привет. Можно ли использовать  в андроид приложениях обычные картинки с jpg, jpeg и  png? Точнее, знаю что можно, но допустимо  ли использовать т.к. у всех разные модели телефонов  а так же диагонали ? Нужно как фон на весь экран так и всплывающие картинки. Чтобы все картинки хорошо отображались вне зависимости от модели телефона. Как понимаю, SVG лучше использовать при создание иконки приложения а так же элементы интерфейса (типо кнопок).

Comment: Во всех приложениях для андроид с открытым исходным кодом, которые я ковырял, для кнопок используется png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всегда лучше использовать SVG, т.к. они могут растягиваться не теряя в качестве.

Использовать не векторную графику тоже можно, если нет возможности SVG использовать. Чтобы выглядело нормально (и не ело слишком много оперативки, что может к `OutOfMemory` ошибке привести) - делайте версии картинки в разных размерах, складывая их в разные папки. `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi` etc. Так система будет брать картинку того или иного размера в зависимости от плотности пикселей экрана.